# Display PIL image in wx python in Windows

Tags: wxpython, python-imaging-library

This code works perfectly on my Ubuntu system, but when I run it on Windows (7 x64-based) the image is not displayed.

This code is part of a more complex system that needs pillow to combine images smoothly into the desired format

Can anyone help please? Might I be missing dependencies or something?

```
import wx
from PIL import Image


class Example(wx.Frame):
    """
        class description
    """
    def __init__(self):
        """
            initialise form
        """
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, 'Title', size=(600, 600))
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        bitmap = wx.Bitmap('circle.png', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
        image = bitmap.ConvertToImage()
        image = self.image_to_pil(image)
        static_bitmap = self.static_bitmap_from_pil_image(self, image)
        sizer.Add(static_bitmap)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Centre()
        self.Layout()

    @staticmethod
    def static_bitmap_from_pil_image(caller, pil_image):
        wx_image = wx.EmptyImage(pil_image.size[0], pil_image.size[1])
        wx_image.SetData(pil_image.convert("RGB").tobytes())
        wx_image.SetAlphaData(pil_image.convert("RGBA").tobytes()[3::4])
        bitmap = wx.BitmapFromImage(wx_image)
        static_bitmap = wx.StaticBitmap(caller, wx.ID_ANY, wx.NullBitmap)
        static_bitmap.SetBitmap(bitmap)
        return static_bitmap

    @staticmethod
    def image_to_pil(image):
        """Convert wx.Image to PIL Image."""
        width, height = image.GetSize()
        data = image.GetData()

        red_image = Image.new("L", (width, height))
        red_image.frombytes(data[0::3])
        green_image = Image.new("L", (width, height))
        green_image.frombytes(data[1::3])
        blue_image = Image.new("L", (width, height))
        blue_image.frombytes(data[2::3])

        if image.HasAlpha():
            alpha_image = Image.new("L", (width, height))
            alpha_image.frombytes(image.GetAlphaData())
            pil_image = Image.merge('RGBA', (red_image, green_image, blue_image, alpha_image))
        else:
            pil_image = Image.merge('RGB', (red_image, green_image, blue_image))
        return pil_image


if __name__ == '__main__':
    """
        initialise application
    """
    simple_screen_app = wx.App()
    main_frame = Example()
    main_frame.Show(True)
    simple_screen_app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 2):

I have commented out the line

```
wx_image.SetAlphaData(pil_image.convert("RGBA").tobytes()[3::4])
```

and it works

Comment: I will not mark this as answered as the line must have some significance in some contexts and my fix will not have universal applicability

Comment: Does the source image have an alpha channel?

Comment: Hi Robin. The test I have done does NOT include an alpha channel, but clearly other images could (and, in fact, will) contain an alpha layer. Any thoughts on what this could mean?

Comment: You should use `SetAlphaData` only in the cases where there is valid alpha channel data.  I'm not exactly sure what `pil_image.convert` is giving you in this case but if it is all zeros or small garbage values then the bitmap will be transparent.

Answer (score 1):

wx.Image.SetAlphaData was removed in newer wxPython versions
Using:

```
Platform  Windows
Windows   10.0.17134
Python    3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 17:13:21) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]
Wx        4.0.4
Pillow    6.1.0
```

I managed to display a image in a wx.StaticBitmap using this conversion method:

```
def pil_image_to_wx_image(pil_img, copy_alpha=True):
    """
    Image conversion from a Pillow Image to a wx.Image.
    """
    orig_width, orig_height = pil_img.size
    wx_img = wx.Image(orig_width, orig_height)
    wx_img.SetData(pil_img.convert('RGB').tobytes())
    if copy_alpha and (pil_img.mode[-1] == 'A'):
        alpha = pil_img.getchannel("A").tobytes()
        wx_img.InitAlpha()
        for i in range(orig_width):
            for j in range(orig_height):
                wx_img.SetAlpha(i, j, alpha[i + j * orig_width])
    return wx_img
```